# Add canvas that takes all window size, and a button in bottom left corner, margined by percentage

Tags: c#, wpf, button, resize, margin

I am trying to have a canvas that takes all window size upon resizing, and a button over it, in the bottom left corner, but which resizes with the window(up to some max size, maybe), and the margin from the button to left and bottom resizes with the window as well.

I have tried to achieve it with a grid like this:

```
<Canvas Background = "LightGray" x:Name="PaintCanvas"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="auto"  Width="auto">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="62*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="87*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button  x:Name="testBut" Content="TEST"
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                MaxHeight="150"  MaxWidth="50" 
            />
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

Edit: it seems that i have to fill the canvas with the grid.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's how i handled it:

Added my grid(with predefined empty cells that serve as margins) as the only child of Window. Then added Canvas as child of grid, but specified it to span across all its rows and columns - filling whole grid(and Window):

```
<Canvas Background="WhiteSmoke" x:Name="PaintCanvas"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

Finally,i put the button in needed cell